# Oracle SQL aggregate on two columns with one condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Having an Oracle 11g table named ztp, data like this:

```
TEAM       PERSON
---------- ----------
T1         P1
T1         P2
T1         P3
T1         P4
T2         P2
T2         P3
T2         P4
T3         P2
T3         P3
T3         P4
T3         P5
T4         P3
T4         P4
T5         P3
T5         P4
T5         P5
```

I want a sql query to aggregate the team and person with this condition:  at least 3 same person joined at least 2 same teams.

for the data now in table ztp, I want the sql query output like this :

```
TEAMS      PERSONS
---------- ----------
T1,T2,T3   P2,P3,P4
T3,T5      P3,P4,P5
```

I only know listagg like this:

```
SELECT TEAM, LISTAGG(PERSON,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERSON) AS PERSONS 
FROM ZTP 
GROUP BY TEAM
```

but the result only aggregate person, and I don't know how to aggregate on two columns with one condition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your example data as text in your question and do not post a screenshot of it. This makes it easier for others to copy the data and to reproduce the problem. Also, the link to the image might become invalid after some time.

Comment: It's better to show test data as text if you want to get fast help.

Comment: OK, I'v included sample data as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't really the two layers of aggregation, if that's you're looking for all combinations of three or more persons - so `listagg()` doesn't work even for that.

I suspect there's a cleaner way, maybe with the model clause; but you could create a list of all the possible combinations of at least three members of each team with [a recursive CTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268):

```
with r (team, persons, members, last_person) as (
  select team, person, 1, person
  from ztp
  union all
  select r.team, r.persons ||','|| z.person, r.members + 1, z.person
  from r
  join ztp z on z.team = r.team and z.person > r.last_person
)
select * from r
where members >= 3;
```

The anchor clause just gets the original data, plus a `members` column to count how many 'aggregated' values there are so we can use that to filter later, and the last person seen so we have that available outside the 'aggregate' string. The recursive member looks for more people in the same team, appending them to the list and incrementing the member count, again for filtering later.

With your sample data that query identifies 12 distinct combinations of three or more people across the five teams:

```
TEAM PERSONS                           MEMBERS LAST_PERSON
---- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
T1   P1,P3,P4                                3 P4         
T1   P1,P2,P4                                3 P4         
T1   P1,P2,P3                                3 P3         
T1   P2,P3,P4                                3 P4         
T2   P2,P3,P4                                3 P4         
T3   P2,P4,P5                                3 P5         
T3   P2,P3,P5                                3 P5         
T3   P2,P3,P4                                3 P4         
T3   P3,P4,P5                                3 P5         
T5   P3,P4,P5                                3 P5         
T1   P1,P2,P3,P4                             4 P4         
T3   P2,P3,P4,P5                             4 P5
```

You can then use `listagg()` against that, filtering on at least two teams with the `having` clause:

```
with r (team, persons, members, last_person) as (
  select team, person, 1, person
  from ztp
  union all
  select r.team, r.persons ||','|| z.person, r.members + 1, z.person
  from r
  join ztp z on z.team = r.team and z.person > r.last_person
)
select listagg(team, ',') within group (order by team) as teams, persons
from r
where members >= 3
group by persons
having count(persons) >= 2;
```

With your sample data (as another CTE here):

```
with ztp (team, person) as (
            select 'T1', 'P1' from dual
  union all select 'T1', 'P2' from dual
  union all select 'T1', 'P3' from dual
  union all select 'T1', 'P4' from dual
  union all select 'T2', 'P2' from dual
  union all select 'T2', 'P3' from dual
  union all select 'T2', 'P4' from dual
  union all select 'T3', 'P2' from dual
  union all select 'T3', 'P3' from dual
  union all select 'T3', 'P4' from dual
  union all select 'T3', 'P5' from dual
  union all select 'T4', 'P3' from dual
  union all select 'T4', 'P4' from dual
  union all select 'T5', 'P3' from dual
  union all select 'T5', 'P4' from dual
  union all select 'T5', 'P5' from dual
),
r (team, persons, members, last_person) as (
  select team, person, 1, person
  from ztp
  union all
  select r.team, r.persons ||','|| z.person, r.members + 1, z.person
  from r
  join ztp z on z.team = r.team and z.person > r.last_person
)
select listagg(team, ',') within group (order by team) as teams, persons
from r
where members >= 3
group by persons
having count(persons) >= 2;

TEAMS                          PERSONS                       
------------------------------ ------------------------------
T1,T2,T3                       P2,P3,P4                      
T3,T5                          P3,P4,P5
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, very precise logic.

Comment: @Alex Poole thank you very much, it does. But runs very slowly when ZTP records  > 100k.  So could the sql be more effective?

Comment: I guess you could pre-filter for teams with at least three people and people in at least two teams, but that might just make things worse by stopping indexes being used by the main query.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a little bit straightforward and can cause some performance issues for large amount of data, but still it can help you to create more precise solution.
The idea is to create groups of person with members count more than 3 and count how many teams that groups take part.

Assumption: there is no comma sign in team or person name.

```
with src as (
select 'T1' as team, 'P1' as person from dual union all
select 'T1','P2' from dual union all
select 'T1','P3' from dual union all
select 'T1','P4' from dual union all
select 'T2','P2' from dual union all
select 'T2','P3' from dual union all
select 'T2','P4' from dual union all
select 'T3','P2' from dual union all
select 'T3','P3' from dual union all
select 'T3','P4' from dual union all
select 'T3','P5' from dual union all
select 'T4','P3' from dual union all
select 'T4','P4' from dual union all
select 'T5','P3' from dual union all
select 'T5','P4' from dual union all
select 'T5','P5' from dual
),
cnct as (
select level lv, team, lpad(' ',level,'  ')||person, sys_connect_by_path(person,',') pth
  from src s1
 connect by person > prior person and team=prior team
)
select tm, ltrim(pth,',')
  from (
    select pth, LISTAGG(team,',') within group ( order by team ) tm
      from cnct  
     where lv >= 3                               
    group by pth
)
where instr(tm,',') > 0
```